# Magento 2: SEO tab not visible in product form

Tags: magento2, seo

SEO tab is not visible in product Edit and ADD form.

I guess this issue occurs after migration but not confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the attribute set for this product. is there a correct group in it and are attributes added to it?
Stores > Attribute Set

[image]

Comment: Hi thankyou for ur response i have bundle of attribute set when i select default mentioned group is available but when i select Migration_Default i the above group is not present there...

Comment: Thanku issue Resolved

Comment: you can create a group in attribute set and add attributes to it. see my screenshot above

Comment: oh, you solved the problem. good luck!